# make_heap memory access problem error: Abort (core dumped)

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-leaks

I am recently writing a SRPT program. I need to use vector and convert the vector into heap using make_heap.
However, I got error on one specific test case `int LB = estimateLB({{2, 2}, {2, 6}}, 2);`

I tested the code on two machines:
Ubuntu will cause the bug, macOS will compile correctly.which is really weird.
The error:

[image]

The brief estimateLB function:

```
int estimateLB(vector<pair<int, int>> proc, int n) {
    int diff = 0;
    int i = 1;

    // 1. cause error
    vector<int> heap;
    heap.push_back(proc[0].first);
    make_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), greater<>{});

    // 2. works
    // vector<int> *heap = new vector<int>();
    // heap->push_back(proc[0].first);
    // make_heap(heap->begin(), heap->end(), greater<>{});

    // memory access problem
    diff = proc[i].second - proc[i - 1].second;

    while (diff > 0) {
        int temp = heap.front();

        if (diff >= temp) {
            pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), greater<>{});
            heap.pop_back();
            diff -= temp;
        }
    }
    heap.push_back(proc[i].first);
    push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), greater<>{});

    return 0;
}
```

If I initialize the vector using pointer, the bug seems to be fixed. For now, I only know the two ways will allocate memory at different location(stack or free storage). Will this mechanism cause this error? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are potentially repeatedly popping elements from a heap that only contains a *single* element.

Comment: It's not a compilation error, it's Undefined Behaviour in your code.

Comment: `heap.push_back(proc[0].first);` -- What if `proc` is empty?  *If I initialize the vector using pointer, the bug seems to be fixed.* -- Nothing was fixed -- all you did was move the corruption bug somewhere else.

Comment: In 1. you place the heap object in the stack frame and in 2. you place it on the heap. The "2. works" suggests you misuse the heap object which the runtime detects when it violates the stack frame but goes undetected when it happens on the heap? Check that proc[0] is a valid call? That is, that you provide a proc with the required elements present. Good luck :)

Comment: FYI -- This program blows up in Visual Studio, right where @KonradRudolph stated.  This is an example of where the logic is wrong, and has absolutely nothing to do with declaring a pointer and calling `new`.

Comment: As @Konrad mentioned, there's a bug in my code. I've updated the Ans. However, it is still weird that macOS won't cause this error. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from @Konrad Rudolph. I end up changing my while loop condition to check the heap is empty or not first.

```
while (diff > 0 && heap->begin() != heap->end()) {}
```

Thanks for all the help :)